# ¿como puedo usar date-range de AdminLTE en mi projecto mvc con .Net core?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

necesito su apoyo para poder integrar correctamente esta parte de esta libreria **AdminLTE** (que la estoy pasando a usar por primera vez), logre integrar muchas de sus vistas y todo, el problema radica en pequeñas objetos que deseo usar en un formulario y no funciona correctamente, les paso a mostrar un poco de mi codigo.

Este es mi

> **_Layout.cshtml** aqui es donde estoy cargando todas mis lebrias que se esta llamando en el

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>- Mensajes Dinamicos -</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/css/skins/skin-green.min.css">
  <!--icheck Minimal theme-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css">
  <!--icheck Theme Midial-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">

  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">

</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-green sidebar-mini">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Main Header -->
    <header class="main-header">
      <!-- Logo -->
      <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
        <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
        <span class="logo-mini">BCP</span>
        <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
        <span class="logo-lg">
                    <img src="~/dist/img/credit/LogoBCP4.png" alt="User Image">
                </span>
      </a>
      <!-- Header Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </a>
        <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
        <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- User Account Menu -->
            <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
              <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
                <img src="~/dist/img/avatar04.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
                <span class="hidden-xs">Leandro Escalera</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <!-- The user image in the menu -->
                <li class="user-header">
                  <img src="~/dist/img/avatar04.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                  <p>
                    Shehryar khan - Coding Infinite
                    <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                  </p>
                </li>
                <!-- Menu Body -->
                <li class="user-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                      <a href="#">Account</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.row -->
                </li>
                <!-- Menu Footer-->
                <li class="user-footer">
                  <div class="pull-left">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar">
      <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <section class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
        <div class="user-panel">
          <div class="pull-left image">
            <img src="~/dist/img/avatar04.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
          </div>
          <div class="pull-left info">
            <p>Leandro Escalera</p>
            <!-- Status -->
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- search form (Optional) -->
        <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
          </div>
        </form>
        <!-- /.search form -->
        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        @Html.Partial("_MainMenu")
        <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
      </section>
      <!-- /.sidebar -->
    </aside>
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
      @RenderBody()
      <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    <!-- Main Footer -->
    <footer class="main-footer">
      <!-- Default to the left -->
      <strong>Copyright &copy; 2019 <a href="https://www.bcp.com.bo/">Banco de Credito BCP</a></strong> - Todos los derechos reservados.
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- ./wrapper -->
  <!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="~/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="~/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

  <script src="~/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>

  <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

  <script src="~/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

estes la seccion Html donde estoy pretendiendo usar este elemento

```html
<div class="box box-primary">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">Date picker</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">

    <!-- Date range -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Date range:</label>

      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation">
      </div>
      <!-- /.input group -->
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

Este llegaria ser la raiz donde copie los elementos de la libreria **AadminLTE**

> **wwwroot**
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor espero su apoyo, les quedare muy agradecido, no se que no estoy llamando mal, estare atento si desean ver mas parte de mi codigo, gracias...

Comment: Verifica en la consola de javascript que todas las referencias en tu proyecto estén correctas, es un poco difícil poder replicar el error desde aquí.

Comment: ok, te explico un poco, el menu del calendario para ser elegido no despliega, solo me parece el input, pero cuando hago click sobre el, no desplega los dos calendarios para elegir las dos fechas.